# bash script build name auth of multiple variables

Tags: bash, rsync

hi I have following problem: I want to copy the content of a folder from a remote machine to may local machine every day at 0:00

the folder is following:

```
/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Backups/Taeglich_YEAR-MONTH-DAY_2300/Databases/
```

I got it till Backups working if i use:

```
SOURCE=/Library/FileMaker\ Server/Data/Backups/
```

and for the rsync command to use the variable $SOURCE:

```
rsync -auP "$SOURCE" /TARGET_DIR
```

I defined the variables YEAR MONTH and DAY and read them from the date function like this:

```
YEAR=`/bin/date +%Y`
MONTH=`/bin/date +%m`
DAY=`/bin/date +%d`
```

how can I combine these variables in one big name string? I tried:

```
rsync -auP "$SOURCE"_"$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY"_2300 /TARGET_DIR
```

but this name string doesn't work, has someone an idea?

Comment: Try using `{}` around variable names like this: `"${SOURCE}_${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}_2300"`

Comment: Please better explain what "doesn't work" means, as we cannot guess the results you are getting, nor those you are expecting.  Also, are your `YEAR`/`DAY`/`MONTH` variables supposed to be part of the source name, or target name?

Comment: `read YEAR MONTH DAY <( date "+%Y %m %d")` Do you really need 3 separate variables, or would `YMD=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` suffice?